# Form's GotFocus event not generating?

Tags: vb.net, forms, focus

### Explanation to my Problem

I am making a project and placed a whole lot of graphical objects on it, including 2-3 buttons. On typing something, like pressing  <kbd>A</kbd> , a particular set of commands should be executed. But this isn't working. I have put all the statements under form's `KeyDown` event.

I tried a lot, after removing all buttons, the statements written under the `KeyDown` event work (That is, the `messagebox` is shown). I think the error I am getting is because the form is not getting focus but there is no such command of setting focus to a form within a form, as far as I know.

- How to **detect** `KeyDown` **when** there are **other objects** placed on the form to **get focus**?

### Example Code

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown () Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        MsgBox("Success") 'Statement example
        'Other KeyDown statements
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the forms KeyPreview property to true.